# $e\precsim f$ and $1-e\precsim 1-f$ imply $e\sim f$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Denote by $\precsim$ the order comes from "Murray-von Neumann" equivalence in the projection lattice of a von Numann algebra. Let e and f be two projections in a  **properly infinit**e von Numann algebra M. Do $e\precsim f$ and $1-e\precsim 1-f$ imply $e\sim f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Take e=0 and 0 < f < 1 such that both f and 1−f are infinite, with (1−f)~1.
Then e≾f because 0≾f for any projection f.
Also 1−e≾1−f because 1≾1−f, which holds by definition of f.

Comment: How about non-zero projections $e$ and $f$?

Comment: You can also take 0 < e < f < 1, with the same properties.  The two properties will continue to hold: the first one by definition, the second one because 1~(1−f).